# Android drawing path with unexpected results

Tags: android-studio, drawing, android-canvas

On the left is the path I want to draw - a check mark.
On the right is what is being drawn - a check mark that's been filled in.  Here is my code.  It's behaving as if after drawing to the 3rd point its returning back to the first point.

```
private void final_line2 (PointF pointA,PointF pointB,Canvas canvas,double radiusmult){
    Path path=new Path();
    path.moveTo(648, 142); Top Right
    path.lineTo(612,428); // Bottom
    path.lineTo(598, 412); // Top left
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.